# Saving passwords from Settings.app

Tags: ios, objective-c, settings.bundle

We are developing application for Enterprise distribution.
One of the main aspects is managing multiple accounts from Settings.app. However we found only one way for saving passwords as plain text into NSUserDefaults.
There is any other way to store passwords securely from Settings.app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `Settings.app` will save only to `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry **NO** there is no way to securely store passwords within the Settings bundle. It will only save to `NSUserDefaults`.

There is however an alternative - and that is to use [InAppSettings](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/) this will allow you to store your passwords securely in the [Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html) or you could implement your own InAppSettings. Where I work they weren't happy using a third party library and asked us to create our own, which to be honest is the long way round. Just look at the links I have provided.